# How to locate a button inside a div with using Selenium WebDriver and C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to use WebDrive (C#) to find and click the following button:

```
<div class="ui-g-12" style="text-align: center">
   <s-button priority="primary" type="button" _nghost-c4="" style="min-width: 80px;">
      <p-tieredmenu _ngcontent-c4="" appendto="body" class="ng-tns-c9-4" id="s-button-1-menu">
         <!---->
      </p-tieredmenu>
      <button _ngcontent-c4="" showdelay="500" tooltipposition="top" class="s-button-with-text s-button-size-default s-button-priority-primary" id="s-button-1" type="button">
         <!----><!----><span _ngcontent-c4="" class="s-button-text ng-star-inserted">Register</span><!---->
      </button>
   </s-button>
</div>
```

I've tried the following options but none of them has been capable of locating this button:

- By Id:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.Id("s-button-1"))));      
  Console.WriteLine(driver.FindElement(By.Id("s-button-1")));
  ```
- By text:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.PartialLinkText("Resgister"))));      
  Console.WriteLine(driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("Resgister")));
  ```
- By xpath:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.XPath("/html/body/s-loading-state/div/div[2]/div/ng-component/ng-component/p-panel/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/s-button/button"))));      
  Console.WriteLine(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/s-loading-state/div/div[2]/div/ng-component/ng-component/p-panel/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/s-button/button")));
  ```

Independent of the selection method used I always get an exception message very similar tho this:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds
 ---> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Register"}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: @Jonah just updated my post with a generic error, independent of the method used to try to find the element, I always get an exception message with `Unable to locate element`

Answer (score 1):

The <kbd>Register</kbd> button is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to locate the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  IWebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("button.s-button-with-text.s-button-size-default.s-button-priority-primary span.s-button-text.ng-star-inserted")));
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  IWebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//button[@class='s-button-with-text s-button-size-default s-button-priority-primary']//span[@class='s-button-text ng-star-inserted' and text()='Register']")));
  ```